# Different css backside with transform

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, keyframe

I have created a css book like this one: https://fiddle.jshell.net/b1b0642z/
Now I need the backside of the cover to be in a different color. I tried to create another div, right after the cover, with this class:

```
.front_back{
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-color:red;
}
```

but it gives me troubles during the transformation (basically while opening the book it randomly shows part of the red div).

Which is the best method to achieve a clean transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried adding another div with the same properties as the `.front` div: can be seen [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/b1b0642z/2/) I basically done what you said but added a z-index to put the image cover a layer above the back inside one.

HTML:

```
<figure class="front-back"></figure>
```

CSS:

```
.front {
     z-index: 1;
}

.front-back {
    animation-name: spincube;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    transform-origin: left;
    width:150px;
    height:200px;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: #333;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Oh that was the missing piece! Thank you!

Comment: @Dani no problem, happy to help :)